# How much should I worry about the 6 month rule on passport validity for visiting Israel?

Tags: passports, regulations, israel

I have reservations on El Al to travel from JFK to Israel on July 5th and return on July 15th.

My US passport expires on January 10, 2016.

The airline told me that they would not let me board because Jan 10 is less than 6 months from July 15th,

At various times El Al customer service reps and a supervisor said it was due to a TSA regulation, a US State Department Regulation, and an Israel requirement. I checked with those sources and was told they have no such requirement, but that some airlines do.

Why would an airline require a passport 6 months after the last date of travel?

Should I jump through the hoops (and spend the money) to get an expedited passport renewal, or just show up at the airport?

Comment: Recently I was told the 6 month deadline is a requirement of icao.int but I did not find it on their website.  Another source said it was a requirement of iata.org but I could not find it on their website either.

Comment: I ended up jumping through the hoops. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49927/seeking-reliabie-website-company-to-renew-usa-passport-quickly

Answer (score 2):

According to [travel.state.gov](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/israel.html), the rule is somewhat vague:

> Although the Israeli government does not require that a passport be valid for six months from the date of entry, airlines routinely do so and may decline boarding if a traveler has less than six months validity on his or her passport.

If you think there is a risk of being denied boarding by your airline, it might be worth trying to get a written statement from the airline stating their policy on passport validity. For example, if the rule they apply is "valid for six months from entry", then you're fine based on the date your passport expires. If the rule is "valid for six months from planned departure", then you're not. Once you get a written statement (as long as it means you can board), bring that with you to airline checkin in case there is any question.

Other unofficial pages have differing views on the topic. From [goisrael.com](http://www.goisrael.com/Tourism_Eng/Tourist%20Information/Planning%20your%20trip/Pages/Visa.aspx):

> All visitors to Israel must hold a passport that is valid for at least six months from the date they are departing the country.​​​​​​

From [World Travel Guide](http://www.worldtravelguide.net/israel/passport-visa):

> To enter Israel, a passport valid for a minimum of six months from the date of entry is required by the nationals referred to in the chart above.

Comment: goisrael.com appears to be an official site of the Israeli Ministry of Tourism.  Granted, their opinion on the subject is less important than that of whichever ministry is responsible for deciding to admit travelers, but still, it's not exactly unofficial.

Comment: @phoog: Good point, I hadn't noticed that it was quasi-official.

Comment: The lack of precision and agreement on official websites are hard to believe, much less understand.  In any case, how likely is it that I have a problem if I show up at the airport with my present passport?  Will the airport personnel be reasonable?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC the airport personnel will almost certainly be reasonable; unfortunately for you, reason dictates that they should deny boarding.  If they transport you to Israel, and you are refused entry, they will be liable for a fine, presumably of significant proportions.

Comment: The US State Dept said that Israel has no 6 month policy but that individual airlines do.  Why would I not be allowed entry to Israel when I get there?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC you can see the information that airlines use to decide whether to let you board by visiting this link: http://www.staralliance.com/en/services/visa-and-health/.  For a US citizen visiting Israel, the requirement is "Passports and/or passport replacing documents must be valid
  for at least 6 months beyond the period of intended stay."

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC maybe the US state department is wrong.  My point is that the airline has that policy because they think Israel has that policy.  Regardless, if the airline has such a policy, then "when I get there" will be never: they won't let you on the plane.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC also, the Israeli foreign ministry says they require the 6-month cushion on their [visa page](http://mfa.gov.il/MFA/ConsularServices/Pages/Visas.aspx), though this is discussing visas that you apply for in advance rather than those you get on arrival.  It's not clear whether the free visa a US visitor gets on arrival is also a B/2 visa.  Maybe Israel has the 6-month rule for some visa types only, in which case you might be able to talk someone into letting you on the plane.  But it's probably less effort just to go down to the passport office and get a new passport.

Comment: @phoog  It is not clear if I can get a new psssport from the passport office in the 8 business days I have.  See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49927/seeking-reliabie-website-company-to-renew-usa-passport-quickly

Comment: @phoog  Israel wants tourists. Israel is not likely to turn away tourists for no good reason.

Comment: @phoog  This site also says Israel does not have such a requirement http://www.uspassporthelpguide.com/six-months-validity-rule/.  It is a balagan, as they would call it in Israel.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC I agree with all your points, but I continue to doubt that you can get the airline to board you with your current passport. In other words, I doubt you'll get *them*  to agree.  Please do let us know if you are able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

They can turn refuse to let you board if they wish, but I have heard from multiple frequent travelers that they really don't care.
Overall El Al is known to be rather relaxed about official regulations as long as you aren't suspicious...
Border control can also always issue you a shorter time period entry permit.

I have a friend that just arrived in Israel on a US passport that isn't good for 6 months and no one said anything to them at all.

Comment: @phoog other airlines might really make an issue, but elal was no problem.