# Seeking reliabie website/company to renew USA passport quickly

Tags: usa, passports, regulations

I am in the states and will travel very soon.  I may want to renew my USA passport within one week.  I am getting the run around from the official State Dept tele number.  Some businesses/websites offer expedited passport renewal for an extra $250.  Are they reliable? Has anyone had experience with particular companies that offer passport renewal services?

(The US State Department site suggests checking any such business with the local Better Business Bureau. I did that for one such service and there were no complaints.)

Comment: What does "very soon" mean? You may be able to renew at a passport agency. The NY office will issue a passport in 8 business days, or sooner if you're traveling before that. To find an agency near you, and its conditions for applications, visit this page: http://www.travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/information/where-to-apply/agencies.html. Then you can at least weigh the certainty of dealing directly with the government, along with the cost of a trip to the office, against the difference in fees and the uncertain credibility of the private expediter.

Comment: Here is the reason.  To use the expedited process one needs an appointent to go to a regional office.  That appoinment can only be obtained from an automated tele number (as the page you linked to says).  The automated number tells me the first available appointments are after the date of my scheduled departure.  If I wait a few days until my departure date is within 7 days, I will be able to speak to an "appointment specialist" who may be able to squeeze me in, but no promises.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC Have you tried appointments with other passport agencies?  Phila, Boston, Washington?

Comment: @Karlson   Yes. I tried the two passport agencies within driving distance.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC what company did you use and what documents did you have to show them ?

Comment: @eramm  My dim memory says it is http://rushpassport.com - The documents needed are listed on their website but are the same as those required by the official US passport offices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the situation:

The Department of State does have some companies that are [registered with them](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/services/expedited/passport-expeditor-courier-companies.html) that are allowed to submit the passport application on behalf of you.

But as Department of State says:

> Customers utilizing courier companies who may call themselves "passport expeditors" **do not receive their passport any faster** than those applying directly at a passport agency.  Courier companies are private companies, some of which are registered at our passport agencies and are allowed to submit passport applications on behalf of customers.

So you can try any of them that are registered but basically what you're paying for is their appointment time.

Comment: And for the convenience of not having to go to the passport office.

Comment: That one remains to be seen...

Comment: @Karlson  Please explain your last comment more fully. It seems important but I do not understand it.

Comment: My comment to phoog or the last sentence in the answer?

Comment: @Karlson Please explain "That one remains to be seen."

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC So instead of going to the passport office in person you are going to a business in person with the same documents in hand.  Which one is preferable or more convenient remains to be seen.

Comment: @Karlson It seems these businesses have standing appointments with the local passport office.  Appointments are very hard to get.  So they are selling their appointment times.  Easy way to make a living!

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC Except for maintaining a good standing with the State Department...  Besides.  I've always renewed passports well in advance, so I never had to go on an emergency basis...

Comment: @Karlson precisely: the convenience of not going to the passport office is variable based on several factors.  In my case, for example, it would not be a significant factor at all since one of my possible commute routes passes within 5 mins walking distance of a passport office.  But for someone who lives at some distance from a passport office, an expediter plus overnight delivery might be far more convenient.

Comment: The passport expediting company I used did, in fact, renew my passport in 3 days, for $250.  Before using them I checked with the Better Business Bureau and there were no reports against them.  It seems they have a nice niche in the market.  They arrange in advance to get special access to the passport office, and the sell that special access to people who need it.  As a US citizen I am not pleased that the State Department gives them special access to the passport office.  But as a traveler, it was helpful.